# Rails (Puma & Passenger) can't find bundled gems after deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I've been working through the PragProg Agile Rails 5 book. I'm hung up on the deployment. I did a straight copy/paste deploy locally with Apache. When I deployed with Capistrano, however, the deployment completes without error, but running `passenger` or `rails s` in the current release directory fails immediately, saying that it can't find the  `listen` gem. Any clue what could be triggering this?

I've ran `bundle package` and `bundle --deployment`. Neither helped. I'm not sure what the dirs are supposed to look like with Capistrano, but the vendor/cache gems aren't in the current dir, even though they're in the development directory.

Here's the what I got in the `production.log`.

```
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.353437 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT DATABASE() as db[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.353879 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT GET_LOCK('2754433143543187260', 0);[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.365473 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.375988 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  `ar_internal_metadata`.* FROM `ar_internal_metadata` WHERE `ar_internal_metadata`.`key` = 'environment' LIMIT 1[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.379731 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.380950 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
D, [2016-12-12T18:47:37.381305 #12570] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT RELEASE_LOCK('2754433143543187260')[0m
```

Apache just says "Incomplete response received from application" when I visit `http://localhost:8080`. I already made sure a secret key was set correctly.

Comment: What does your `vendor/cache` directory look like on the server? Is it empty?

Comment: I have no `vendor/cache`. I just have `vendor/bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

I just reran the scenario, and things worked:

https://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-50/section-16.html

https://intertwingly.net/tmp/deploydepot.html

Here's what I have in `vendor/cache`:

`rubys@rubixb:~/deploy/depot/releases/current$ ls vendor/cache/
activemerchant-1.62.0.gem              mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem
activemodel-serializers-xml-1.0.1.gem  mini_portile2-2.1.0.gem
airbrussh-1.1.1.gem                    minitest-5.9.1.gem
arel-7.1.4.gem                         multi_json-1.12.1.gem
bcrypt-3.1.11.gem                      mysql2-0.4.5.gem
builder-3.2.2.gem                      net-scp-1.2.1.gem
byebug-9.0.6.gem                       net-ssh-3.2.0.gem
capistrano-3.7.0.gem                   nio4r-1.2.1.gem
capistrano-bundler-1.2.0.gem           nokogiri-1.6.8.1.gem
capistrano-harrow-0.5.3.gem            pg-0.19.0.gem
capistrano-passenger-0.2.0.gem         puma-3.6.2.gem
capistrano-rails-1.2.0.gem             rack-2.0.1.gem
capistrano-rvm-0.1.2.gem               rack-test-0.6.3.gem
coffee-rails-4.2.1.gem                 rails-dom-testing-2.0.1.gem
coffee-script-2.4.1.gem                rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3.gem
coffee-script-source-1.11.1.gem        rake-12.0.0.gem
concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem              sass-rails-5.0.6.gem
debug_inspector-0.0.2.gem              spring-2.0.0.gem
erubis-2.7.0.gem                       sprockets-3.7.0.gem
execjs-2.7.0.gem                       sprockets-rails-3.2.0.gem
ffi-1.9.14.gem                         sqlite3-1.3.12.gem
globalid-0.3.7.gem                     sshkit-1.11.4.gem
haml-4.0.7.gem                         thor-0.19.4.gem
i18n-0.7.0.gem                         thread_safe-0.3.5.gem
jbuilder-2.6.1.gem                     tilt-2.0.5.gem
jquery-rails-4.2.1.gem                 turbolinks-5.0.1.gem
jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1.gem              turbolinks-source-5.0.0.gem
kaminari-0.17.0.gem                    tzinfo-1.2.2.gem
loofah-2.0.3.gem                       uglifier-3.0.4.gem
mail-2.6.4.gem                         websocket-driver-0.6.4.gem
method_source-0.8.2.gem                websocket-extensions-0.1.2.gem
mime-types-3.1.gem`